# Why war packaging creates maven problem "Could not calculate build plan: error in opening zip file"?

Tags: maven-2, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

First of all, I am working with
STS 2.6.1 R1 IDE
maven 2.2.1

I created a new maven project (simple archetype)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  

<groupId>org.dsample</groupId>  

<artifactId>root</artifactId> 

<version>0.0.1</version>  

<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Added a maven module to that project with a war packaging
and I get the Maven Problem in Markers tab:

> "Could not calculate build plan: error in opening zip file"

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Kind Regards,
Despot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer inspection of the stack trace from the command prompt when running the mvn clean install -Dmaven.skip.test=true command I solved the issue:

> C:\pathToRootOfProject>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
>   [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] FATAL ERROR [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Error building POM (may not be
>   this project's POM).
>
> Project ID: unknown
>
> Reason: Could not find the model file
>   'pathToRootOfProject\xxx'. for project
>   unknown
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Trace
>   org.apache.maven.reactor.MavenExecutionException:
>   Could not find the model file
>   'pathToRootOfProject\xxx'. for project
>   unknown
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:404)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:272)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
>
> ```
>     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
> ```
>
> Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException:
>   Could not find the model file
>   'pathToRootOfProject\xxx'. for project
>   unknown
>           at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1575)
>           at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromSourceFileInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:506)
>           at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.build(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:200)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProject(DefaultMaven.java:604)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:487)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:560)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjects(DefaultMaven.java:391)
>           ... 12 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   pathToRootOfProject\xxx (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
>           at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlReader.(XmlReader.java:124)
>           at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamReader.(XmlStreamReader.java:67)
>           at hidden.org.codehaus.plexus.util.ReaderFactory.newXmlReader(ReaderFactory.java:118)
>           at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1570)
>           ... 18 more [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: < 1 second [INFO]
>   Finished at: Mon Jun 06 20:42:19 CEST
>   2011 [INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M
>
> ### [INFO]

Now I renamed one of my modules but the child name (xxx) was left in my root pom.xml:

```
<modules>  
    <module>a</module>  
    <module>b</module>  
    <module>c</module>  
    <module>xxx</module>  
    <module>d</module>  
    <module>f</module>  
</modules>
```

Once I deleted that line, and rebuild the project, the issue disappeared.

Cheers,
Despot

Comment: Actually now I am able to successfully build, but still get the maven errors... odd.